# SharePoint 2007 Date picker issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, custom-lists

We have a issue in SharePoint custom list new form.aspx page. We have 2 date fields, it was previously showing calendar icon with the date field but now it is not using calendar icon this the date fields in new and edit form page.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Please add a solution if you found one. For me also the date picker doesn't show up on browsers other than IE. In IE too, the date picker appears but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug. Use **INTERNET EXPLORER ONLY** to access moss sites.

Comment: Happening in chrome as well.

Comment: Add your site in compatibility view in IE.